# Как правильно писать? "До" или "по"?

Tags: орфография

С первого по четырнадцатое, или с первого до четырнадцатого?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно использование обоих вариантов, предлоги ДО и ПО в значении времени соответствуют друг другу. Обычно, предлог ПО используют, если после дат следует или подразумевается "включительно", однако это не является правилом, и вариант "с первого до четырнадцатого включительно" также допустим (подробнее [тут](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/hardwords?layout=item&id=25_317)).

Answer (score 1):

**Возможные варианты:** с первого по четырнадцатое,  с первого по четырнадцатое (включительно), с первого до четырнадцатого (включительно).

**Из словаря**

**Предлог ДО кого-чего.** 1. Указывает на **пространственный, временной или количественный** предел действия, движения, состояния, качества и т.п. Дожить до ста лет.  Проспать до обеда. 3. Указывает на действие, которому предшествует другое действие. Уехать до первых заморозков.  Это лекарство нужно принимать до еды.

**Предлог ПО кого-что.** Употр. при указании **временного** предела действия, состояния; **соответствует по значению предлогу ДО**. По сей день. Проездной действителен по март месяц. Оплата с января по апрель.

Предлог ПО обычно используется,  если нужно указать **точный временной интервал, включая предельные значения** (В.п. охватывает предмет целиком), например: В трехэтажном здании учились гимназистки с первого по седьмой класс.

**Предлог ДО (Р.п.)** обозначает распространение действия **до границ предмета** и обычно используется в тех случаях, когда не требуется указание на точное количество: И Артем прошел войну с первого до последнего дня и закончил ее командиром полка.

Во избежание непонимания в документах желательно использовать **наречие "включительно" в обоих случаях**, но в первую очередь это касается предлога ДО