# Есть ли разница между «до» и «по»?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли разница между "по" и "до"? 
Например: 
"Ехал на поезде с 1 до 4 числа". Или "с 1 по 3" — имеется в виду, что это последнее действие чего-либо?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно писать? "До" или "по"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424427/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%94%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be)

Answer (score 2):

Согласно Большому толковому словарю,

> **ПО** Употр. при указании временного предела действия, состояния; соответствует по значению предлогу **до**.

Таким образом, разницы в употреблении этих предлогов во временном контексте нет:

> Проездной действителен по 1 апреля = Проездной действителен до 1 апреля

В обоих случаях может возникнуть двусмысленность в отношении того, включать ли последний отрезок в данный период; для ее устранения используют наречие "включительно":

> ... Издательство «Пролетарий» придралось к тому, что по договору оно имеет право владеть ее сочинениями **по** 1 янв. **включительно** ... (К. Чуковский)
>
> Так было издревле ― **до** конца 19 века **включительно**. (И. Ильин)

Comment: Простой вопрос: подразумевание "включительно" ещё не считается нормой? По теме: [Коварные предлоги "до" и "по"](https://apno.ru/press-tsentr/publikatsii/44964-kovarnye-predlogi-do-i-po).

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить о датах, вариант с "по" *однозначно* включает конечную названную. Вариант же "до..." буквально означает "*до наступления* названной даты" (включая только предшествующую, не названную), но на практике вызывает неясность, поэтому в формальных случаях (объявление и т. п.) его избегают (употребляют "по" и даже уточняющее слово "включительно").